# osfp route filtering directly connected route

Tags: routing, ospf

I am using Cisco 2960XR switch

192.168.1.0/24 is directly connected on gi1/0/1

192.168.97.0/24 is directly connected on gi1/0/7

```
router ospf 10
network 192.168.1.0
network 192.168.97.0
```

q1) how do i prevent direct route 192.168.1.0/24 from being advertised out of gi1/0/7 ?

can anyone give an example

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

If there isn’t another router on the subnet, simply remove the network statement under the OSPF configuration.